# NSArray with componentsSeparatedByString memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm having problems with memory leaks with this function. I thought creating an NSArray with componentsSeparatedByString was autorelease but instruments seems to indicate a leak at the NSArray aPair. Why would it indicate a leak there and not also at the other NSArrays created in the same way?

```
-(void) checkRequest: (NSString *)request view:(UIViewController *)theView webView:(UIWebView *)wView
{
    //NSLog(@"JSResponder - checkRequest()");

    NSString *aRequest = [NSString stringWithString:request];

    NSArray *urlArray = [aRequest componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];

    if([urlArray count] > 1)
    {
        NSString *paramsString = [urlArray lastObject];
        NSString *cmd = @"";

        NSArray *urlParamsArray = [paramsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];  
        int numCommands = [urlParamsArray count];

        NSMutableDictionary *paramsWithNames = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc ]                        initWithCapacity:numCommands];

        for (NSString *elementPair in urlParamsArray)
        {
            NSArray *aPair = [elementPair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];

            NSString *aKey = [aPair objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *aParam = [aPair objectAtIndex:1]; 

            if([aKey compare:@"_command"] == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                cmd = aParam;
            }   
            else 
            {
                [paramsWithNames setValue: aParam forKey:aKey];
            }
        }

        [self executeCommand: cmd withParams: paramsWithNames view:theView webView:wView];

        [paramsWithNames release];
    }
}
```

This function get called by the following:

```
    - (void)pullJSEvent:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    NSLog(@"MainView - pullJSEvent()");

    NSString *jsCall = [NSString stringWithString:@"if(typeof checkOBJCEvents == 'function'){checkOBJCEvents();}"];

    NSString *jsAnswer = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall] retain];

    if([jsAnswer compare:@"none"] != NSOrderedSame)
    {
        //NSLog(@"           answer => %@", jsAnswer);
        [jsResponder checkRequest:jsAnswer view:(UIViewController *)self webView:self.webView];
    }
    [jsAnswer release];
}
```

Thank-you

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to dig a bit deeper with the Leaks instrument. You're leaking one of the strings in the array, not the array itself. Leaks indicates that line because that's where the strings in the array are allocated.

Go into Leaks, look at a leaked instance, and click that little arrow button. You'll see all the retains and releases of the leaked object, which should point you to the problem.

[image: Leaks]